Loop takes too long to execute
I understand this error indicates infinite loop.
I strongly believe the root cause might be related to garbage value or incorrect data in the variable or assignment.
Can you please help?
calcTrailingStopLoss(entryType = "None") =>
    var float slMult = 0
    var float stopLossValueTSL = na
    var float slPointsTSL = na
    var float entryValueTSL = na
    var bool enableLongTSL = false
    var bool enableShortTSL = false
    var int rRTSL = na
    var float prevStopLossValue = na
    rRTSL := str.endswith(strategy.opentrades.entry_id(0),"SL") ? 2 : varRRTSL
    if entryType == "Long"
        stopLossValueTSL := stopLossValueLong
        slPointsTSL := slPointsLong
        entryValueTSL := entryValueLong
    else if entryType == "Short"
        stopLossValueTSL := stopLossValueShort
        slPointsTSL := slPointsShort
        entryValueTSL := entryValueShort
    slMult :=  math.floor(math.abs(close-stopLossValueTSL)/slPointsTSL)
    prevStopLossValue := stopLossValueTSL
    //[currentCandleHealthPer, currentCandleBody] = getCandleHealthPer(0)
    if  bar_index >= debugBarIndex-50 and bar_index <=debugBarIndex+50
        log.warning("calcTrailingStopLoss - slMult Before:{0}",slMult)
    //Checking if system current candle is elligible for trailling
    if isGreen and entryType == "Long" and (candleHealthPer >= varCandleHealthPer) and ((close > (entryValueTSL+(rRTSL*slPointsTSL)) and (stopLossValueTSL < close) and (strategy.position_size[1] > 0 and strategy.position_size > 0)) or (math.abs(close - entryValueTSL) >= (entryValueTSL*0.005) or dailyPoints >= entryValueTSL*0.005))
        enableLongTSL := true
    else if isRed and entryType == "Short" and (candleHealthPer >= varCandleHealthPer) and ((close < (entryValueTSL-(rRTSL*slPointsTSL)) and stopLossValueTSL < close and isRed and (strategy.position_size[1] < 0 and strategy.position_size < 0)) or (math.abs(close - entryValueTSL) >= entryValueTSL*0.005 or dailyPoints >= entryValueTSL*0.005))
        enableShortTSL := true
        
    //Trailing logic
    //Trailing logic
    if enableLongTSL or enableShortTSL
        //for i=0 to slMult//-1
        while slMult>=1 and ((entryType == "Long" and stopLossValueTSL+(slPointsTSL) <= low) or (entryType == "Short" and stopLossValueTSL-(slPointsTSL) >= high))
            if entryType == "Long"
                stopLossValueTSL := slMult ==1 ? (stopLossValueTSL + slPointsTSL) - tSLMarginPer : stopLossValueTSL + slPointsTSL
            else if entryType == "Short"
                stopLossValueTSL := slMult ==1 ? (stopLossValueTSL - slPointsTSL) + tSLMarginPer : stopLossValueTSL - slPointsTSL

            slMult := slMult-1
            //if  bar_index >= debugBarIndex-50 and bar_index <=debugBarIndex+50
            //    log.warning("calcTrailingStopLoss - slMult After:{0}",slMult)
        if entryType == "Long" and (prevStopLossValue < stopLossValueTSL)
            //log.info("calcTrailingStopLoss - inside label printing")
            label.new(bar_index, high, text="SL="+ str.tostring(stopLossValueTSL)+"|slP="+str.tostring(slPointsTSL), color=color.new(color.green, 80))
        else if entryType == "Short" and (prevStopLossValue > stopLossValueTSL)
            label.new(bar_index, low, text="SL="+ str.tostring(stopLossValueTSL)+"|slP="+str.tostring(slPointsTSL), color=color.new(color.red, 80),style = label.style_label_up)
        //log.info("calcTrailingStopLoss - enableLongTSL:{0}|enableShortTSL:{1}|prevStopLossValue:{2}|stopLossValueTSL:{3}|slMult:{4}",enableLongTSL,enableShortTSL,prevStopLossValue,stopLossValueTSL,slMult)
        enableLongTSL := false
        enableShortTSL := false
    [stopLossValueTSL, enableLongTSL, enableShortTSL]

I get error on line (slMult := slMult-1) at different candles, on specific conditions, not always. Can you advise what is the exact problem here?
I tried putting logs and manual calculations to understand why it is failing but no luck. There is no way my calculations can take this long time, there has to be some leaks or garbage value that is cause this issue.

Might be helpful if you can post with input data as well as actual error message. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
